# jQuery Chosen: How to search in title of option

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

i am using a selectbox in combination with the jQuery chosen plugin. I gave each option a value (4 digit code) and a title (description of the code).

I want the plugin to search in the title as well when i type something in the searchbox. Currently it is just working for the inner text of the option.

Has someone done this before or does someone know how to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: please read on [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue that you face and managed to solve it by manipulating the Chosen plugin js library.

Basically, you need to look for the lines with option.html because the search filter is working with ***option.html***.

Instead of only working with option.html, we now want it to filter using the option's title attribute as well, which is the ***option.title*** in this case.

Search for the line with **AbstractChosen.prototype.winnow_results = function() {**.

This is the **original code** within the function:

```
      option.search_text = option.group ? option.label : option.html;
      if (!(option.group && !this.group_search)) {
        option.search_match = this.search_string_match(option.search_text, regex);
        if (option.search_match && !option.group) {
          results += 1;
        }
        if (option.search_match) {
          if (searchText.length) {
            startpos = option.search_text.search(zregex);
            text = option.search_text.substr(0, startpos + searchText.length) + '</em>' + option.search_text.substr(startpos + searchText.length);
            option.search_text = text.substr(0, startpos) + '<em>' + text.substr(startpos);
          }
          if (results_group != null) {
            results_group.group_match = true;
          }
        } else if ((option.group_array_index != null) && this.results_data[option.group_array_index].search_match) {
          option.search_match = true;
        }
```

Let's change this to:

```
      option.search_text = option.group ? option.label : option.html;
      if (!(option.group && !this.group_search)) {
        option.search_match = this.search_string_match(option.html, regex) || this.search_string_match_title(option.title, regex);
        option.search_match_title = this.search_string_match_title(option.title, regex);
        if (option.search_match && !option.group) {
          results += 1;
        }
        if (option.search_match) {
          if (searchText.length) {
            if (option.search_match_title) {
                startpos = option.title.search(zregex);
            }
            else {
                startpos = option.search_text.search(zregex);
                text = option.search_text.substr(0, startpos + searchText.length) + '</em>' + option.search_text.substr(startpos + searchText.length);
                option.search_text = text.substr(0, startpos) + '<em>' + text.substr(startpos);
            }
          }
          if (results_group != null) {
            results_group.group_match = true;
          }
        } else if ((option.group_array_index != null) && this.results_data[option.group_array_index].search_match) {
          option.search_match = true;
        }
```

Now look for another piece of code below:

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.search_string_match = function(search_string, regex) {
  var part, parts, _i, _len;
  if (regex.test(search_string)) {
    return true;
  } else if (this.enable_split_word_search && (search_string.indexOf(" ") >= 0 || search_string.indexOf("[") === 0)) {
    parts = search_string.replace(/\[|\]/g, "").split(" ");
    if (parts.length) {
      for (_i = 0, _len = parts.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        part = parts[_i];
        if (regex.test(part)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

After which, you just have to **insert** the following code below the above function:

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.search_string_match_title = function(search_string, regex) {
  var part, parts, _i, _len;
  if (regex.test(search_string)) {
    return true;
  } 
};
```

Hope this helps.